# How does timer_tick execute the code block?

Tags: c#, .net

Does timer execute the code block each tick even if the code block not completely done ? and if the answer is yes how to make timer tick completes the code block and then start over again.

Comment: Stop the timer as it enters the timer elapse event and start in finally block to ensure it must started.

Comment: Please refer to the official documentation for the [Timer Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the link @3vts

Comment: use recursive approach without timer, will timer library load in program

Comment: Thanks for this tip @AhsanAzizAbbasi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does execute the code each tick even if it's still not done. What you can do is when you execute the code block, stop the timer first, then run it again after the execution of the code block is done.

```
void Tick_Event(...){
timer.Stop();
// Do something
timer.Start();
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks it helps alot

Answer (score 1):

yes you can stop and then start the timer again once you are done with your time taking logic.

```
void myTick_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myTick.Stop();            

    // your time taking logic here that may take upto some minutes

    myTick.Start();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the useful answer